# SpringBoot 3 (Data) keyword isTrue doesn't work

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm seeing something strange after upgrading my app to SpringBoot 3 from SpringBoot 2.

The application relies on an existing database (MySQL) which doesn't use good practices. One of them is using `Y` `N` for booleans stored in a VARCHAR.

To make things easier on the Java side, I created a converter that looks like this:

```java
@Converter
public class BooleanToStringConverter implements AttributeConverter<Boolean, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Boolean attribute) {
        if (attribute == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return attribute ? "Y" : "N";
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        if (dbData == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return dbData.equals("Y");
    }
}
```

And on my beans I use it as:

```java
@Column(name = "DELIVERED")
@Convert(converter = BooleanToStringConverter.class)
private Boolean delivered;
```

So far so good.

If I create a repository to query all delivered entities I'd write something like this in SpringBoot 2:

```
List<MyClass> findAllByDeliveredIsTrue();
```

But if I run this in SpringBoot 3 it returns an empty list.

I need to write the query manually to make it work.

```
@Query("SELECT c FROM MyClass c WHERE c.delivered = true")
List<MyClass> findAllByDeliveredIsTrue();
```

Any idea why it's happening?

---

Edit:

I've enabled SQL Logs and definitely queries are created differently. For sake of simplicity I translated some things on the post because on real scenario the database is in Spanish and it uses `S`/`N` instead of `Y`/`N`.

```java
Java service
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        log.error("DEBUG INIT");
        repo.findFirstByActiuIsTrueOrderByDataDesc();
        repo.findFirstByActiuIsTrueOrderByDataDesc1(); ///Working case
        log.error("DEBUG END");
    }
```

```java
Repository

//Failing case
Optional<Condicio> findFirstByActiuIsTrueOrderByDataDesc();


@Query("SELECT c FROM Condicio c WHERE c.actiu = true ORDER BY c.data ASC")
Optional<Condicio> findFirstByActiuIsTrueOrderByDataDesc1(); //Working case
```

```
2023-05-13T10:23:19.336+02:00 ERROR 42936 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.a.backend.service.CondicioService    : DEBUG INIT
Hibernate: select c1_0.COND_CONDICIO,c1_0.COND_ACTIU,c1_0.COND_DATA,c1_0.COND_DESCRIPCIO from CONDICIONS c1_0 where c1_0.COND_ACTIU order by c1_0.COND_DATA desc limit ?
Hibernate: select c1_0.COND_CONDICIO,c1_0.COND_ACTIU,c1_0.COND_DATA,c1_0.COND_DESCRIPCIO from CONDICIONS c1_0 where c1_0.COND_ACTIU='S' order by c1_0.COND_DATA asc
2023-05-13T10:23:19.451+02:00 ERROR 42936 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.a.backend.service.CondicioService    : DEBUG END
```

Comment: Are you sure that the repository is properly auto-configured as JPA repository by Spring Boot? Did the same code actually work in Spring Boot 2? Can you see in the logs: "Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories" and "Found NNN JPA repository interfaces"

Comment: If "SELECT c FROM MyClass c WHERE c.delivered = *true*" works, doesn't that mean that DELIVERED is actually a BOOLEAN and not a VARCHAR?

Comment: The same code works in SB 2. The JPA is properly configured and I see the mentioned log. Also, rewriting the query as `findAllByDelivered(Boolean delivered);` would work. As mentioned, at database layer the underlying type is VARCHAR and a converter is used

Comment: @AlexRoig have you tried **to not** use `is` verb? i.e. `findAllByDeliveredTrue` instead of `findAllByDeliveredIsTrue`?

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov Please state exactly how changing the method name as you suggest could possibly fix this problem. It can't.

Comment: @OP There is no such thing as an `isTrue` keyword anywhere in your post. Please clarify.

Comment: @user207421 I would suggest to read [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) first: "True findByActiveTrue() … where x.active = true"

Comment: You are carefully handling "null" as a third possible value.  Perhaps the problem is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it's an issue on CriteriaBuilder on Spring Data. The issue is being tracked on the [repository issue #2800](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/2800). At the moment of answering it's still not resolved and affected versions are at least `Spring Boot 3.0.2`

Answer (score 1):

The code you showed does not work with a boolean, but rather a tri-state value.  Decide what you will do with NULLs.  Then be sure to have 3 cases throughout your code.

I would not bother trying to fix the yes/no being in a VARCHAR unless you can actually fix the schema and the data.  Instead, test for `== 'N'` as needed.  (I picked the "no" side because that works with most European languages.

Note, however, that `== 'Y'` is not the same as `!= 'N'` -- because of the NULL option.

Also, check that the `COLLATION` of that `VARCHAR` is case-folding so that 'n' == 'N'.  The collation name should end in `_ci``.

Comment: Null handling is a good point but the BooleanToString converter implementation I have already covers it. The thing is that these queries worked on SpringBoot 2 and out of the blue on Spring Boot 3 they no longer work. It looks like there's some new query optimiser that replaces the JPQL to `c1_0.COND_ACTIU` to implicitly test the boolean true state instead of specifying it and as it doesn't go through the converter, the DB doesn't actually know what to compare it against. The DB is something I can't change and there's a custom ERP and we don't have control over it.